# How to arrange (dplyr) a data frame by "date" field?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a dataframe `df`, with column called "`date`".
When I want to arrange by date: `df %>% arrange(date)`
I get the following error:

```
error in arrange_impl(.data, dots) : 
  cannot arrange column of class 'function' at position 1
```

Apart of changing the column name, what is the way of forcing it to arrange by this column?

Comment: Please add a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: It's a general question, take any df with "date" column name.

Comment: @akrun it's ok, there was a misunderstanding. I see that without changing the name of the column from date to other name it woudln't work. But for some reason groupby takes it without any problem, do you know why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `backquotes` to specify the column names with leading/lagging white spaces

```
df %>%
   arrange(` date `)
```

---

Or better would be to `rename` the columns by removing the white spaces  (`trimws`) and then use `arrange` as in the OP's code.

```
df %>%
  rename_all(trimws) %>%
  arrange(date)
```

NOTE: It is better to not have spaces in column names whether leading/lagging or separating words.  Usually, if there are multiple words in a column names, use underscore (`_`) to connect it.

---

If the column names doesn't have any whitespaces ('df1'), both `group_by` after `arrange` or `arrange` after `group_by` would work well

```
df1 %>%
   group_by(date) %>% 
   arrange(col2)
# A tibble: 6 x 2
# Groups: date [6]
#  date         col2
#  <date>      <dbl>
#1 2018-03-26 -0.848
#2 2018-03-27 -0.584
#3 2018-03-29 -0.466
#4 2018-03-28  0.266
#5 2018-03-30  0.445
#6 2018-03-31  0.847

df1 %>% 
    group_by(col2) %>%
     arrange(date)
# A tibble: 6 x 2
# Groups: col2 [6]
#  date         col2
#  <date>      <dbl>
#1 2018-03-26 -0.848
#2 2018-03-27 -0.584
#3 2018-03-28  0.266
#4 2018-03-29 -0.466
#5 2018-03-30  0.445
#6 2018-03-31  0.847
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
df <- data.frame(" date " = sample(Sys.Date() + 0:5), col2 = rnorm(6), check.names = FALSE)

df1 <- df
colnames(df1)[1] <- "date"
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167615/discussion-on-answer-by-akrun-how-to-arrange-dplyr-a-data-frame-by-date-fiel).